# a script to replace mkdir -p command

Tags: shell-script, mkdir

I'm writing a script that replaces the mkdir -p command. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh  

n=1;
max=50;
while [ "$n" -le "$max" ]; do
mkdir "s$n"
n='expr "$n" + 1';
done
```

I should be able to then use this script to type in aaa/bbb/ccc and it'll make these directories.

Comment: Which `-p` "command" are you referring to?  Can you provide input and expected output?  What does not work in what you have thus far tried?

Comment: `alias mkdir='mkdir -p'` if all you're trying to do is save yourself some typing.

Answer (score 3):

execute the script as below.

> ./script.sh abc/def/ghi/jkl

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_LIST=${1}

IFS=/
for DIR_NAME in ${DIR_LIST}
do
    mkdir ${DIR_NAME}
    cd ${DIR_NAME}
done
```

Comment: @KingBoi If you are satisfied and this solve your question, you should consider to take a minute to thanks Kamaraj by accepting his answer.

Comment: @KingBoi And upvoting!

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive function:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir_p() {
    local path=$1
    local parent=${path%/*}
    [[ ${path} != /* ]] && parent=${PWD}/${parent}
    [[ ! -d $parent ]] && mkdir_p "${parent}"
    [[ ! -d $path ]] && mkdir "${path}"
}
mkdir_p "${1}"
```